# How to use launchctl to reload changes to plist?

Tags: macos, plist, launchctl

On MaxOS I created ~/Library/LaunchAgents/x.plist.  Then I loaded it with "launchctl load ..."

I made some edits, unloaded and reloaded it.  When I type "launchctl list x" it does not display any of my mods to the plist file.

How can I get launchctl to load my new changes? How is it remembering the first version of this file even after I unloaded it?  Does it use a cache?

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way to update is:

```sh
# copy the new file to ~/Library/LaunchAgents

sudo launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/x.plist
sudo launchctl load   ~/Library/LaunchAgents/x.plist
```